# how to improve the speed of the python script

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm very new to python. I'm working in the area of hydrology and I want to learn python to assist me with processing hydrological data.

At the moment I write a script to extract bits of information from a big data set. I have three csv files:

Complete_borelist.csv

Borelist_not_interested.csv

Elevation_info.csv

I want to create a file with has all the bores that are in complete_borelist.csv but not in borelist_not_interested.csv. I also want to grab some information from complete_borelist.csv and Elevation_info.csv for those bores which satisfy the first criteria.

My script is as follow:

```
not_interested_list =[]
outfile1 = open('output.csv','w')
outfile1.write('Station_ID,Name,Easting,Northing,Location_name,Elevation')
outfile1.write('\n')
with open ('Borelist_not_interested.csv','r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        if not line.startswith('Station'):  #ignore header
            line = line.rstrip()
            words = line.split(',')
            station = words[0]
            not_interested_list.append(station)
with open('Complete_borelist.csv','r') as f2:
    next(f2)   #ignore header
    for line in f2:
        line= line.rstrip()
        words = line.split(',')
        station = words[0]
        if not station in not_interested_list:
            loc_name = words[1]
            easting = words[4]
            northing = words[5]
            outfile1.write(station+','+easting+','+northing+','+loc_name+',')
            with open ('Elevation_info.csv','r') as f3:
                next(f3)    #ignore header
                for line in f3:
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    data = line.split(',')
                    bore_id = data[0]
                        if bore_id == station:
                            elevation = data[4]
                            outfile1.write(elevation)
                            outfile1.write ('\n')                      

outfile1.close()
```

I have two issues with the script:

The first is the Elevation_info.csv doesn't have information for all the bore in the Complete_borelist.csv. When my loop get to the station where it can't find Elevation record for it, the script doesn't write "null" but continue to write the information for the next station in the same line. Can anyone help me to fix this please?

The second is my complete borelist is about >200000 rows and my script runs through them very slow. Can anyone have any suggestion to make it run faster?

Very much appreciated and sorry if my question is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

performance-wise, this has a couple of problems. The first one is that you are opening and re-reading the Elevation info for every line of the complete file.. Read the elevation info into a dictionary keyed upon the bore_id before you open the complete file. Then you can test the dictionary very fast to see if station is in it instead of re-reading.

The second performance issue is that you don't stop searching in the bore_id list once you find a match. The dictionary idea solves that too, but otherwise a break once you have a match would help a little.

For the null printing problem, you just need to outfile1.write("\n") if the bore_id is not in the dictionary. An else statement on the dictionary test does that. In the current code, an else closing the for loop would do it. Or even changing the indentation of that last write("\n").

Comment: Thank you very much. It works in a few seconds now :)